# Is there a way to roll back inside a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, rollback

In a stored procedure, several "update" sql statements are being called.  If any of them fails, I want to roll back the previously executed update statements in the same stored procedure.  Is there a way?

Comment: Which answer you like will depend on whether you mean, "Roll back every previous update," or "Roll back TO the previous update."  Ben and I read your question differently.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the whole thing in a begin tran/end tran.  To quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx):

> BEGIN TRANSACTION represents a point at which the data referenced by a
>   connection is logically and physically consistent. If errors are
>   encountered, all data modifications made after the BEGIN TRANSACTION
>   can be rolled back to return the data to this known state of
>   consistency. Each transaction lasts until either it completes without
>   errors and COMMIT TRANSACTION is issued to make the modifications a
>   permanent part of the database, or errors are encountered and all
>   modifications are erased with a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement.

In response to your comment, combining this with nested [Try/Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=sql.110).aspx) might work for you.

Comment: I don't think this meets the OP's requirements. He wants it such that if the second one fails, roll back to just after the first.

Comment: Rereading:  Are you sure?  He says, "If any of them fails, I want to roll back the previously executed update statements in the same stored procedure."  Roll them all back, not just the first.

Comment: In the above example, if the first fails, not execute the remaining two. If the second update fails, I want to roll back the first and not execute the third.  If the third fails, roll back the first two.

Comment: My fault; my mind inserted the word "to" as in "roll back *to* the previously executed..."